# Windows XP update to .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 KB976569 taking forever

Tags: windows-xp, automatic-update

On several machines, KB976569 install via Automatic Updates is taking forever. The message
is "Installing MIcrosoft .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 Update for Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP x86 (KB976569) (update 1 of 1)" forever.  Ok, 7+ hours and counting.

The overall progress bar is stuck around 50%, and isn't moving. No task in the process list is using any CPU time, (all are at 0% except taskmgr, and system/svchost type stuff).

I have found [discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winserverwsus/thread/92ab96d2-b754-4014-9c3e-5b20faab620c) but no solution using google. I suspect that this is a glitch where Windows Update decided to install an update to something that isn't actually installed, and thus, the update fails to install. A core defect in their Auto Update architecture that results in unapplicable updates getting detected as required.

Answer (score 1):

Known issue with anti-virus.  If you have AV running, especially Kaspersky or Norton, try disabling them to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: We have panda corporate and there is no way to disable it other than an uninstall. (Good reason why Panda is a rotten anti-virus.)

Comment: My money is on the AV.  Panda is a really buggy program.  Check with your Admin to see if you can try it on one PC segregated from the network or something to see if it fixes it.

Comment: I have the network admin password, and I can remove Panda, so I'm trying that.

Comment: Let me know if it works!

Comment: Didn't work, but killing the three msiexec.exe processes twice, followed by a visit to Windows Update site, instead of relying on automatic-updates, seems to have jogged the system out of wanting to install this update.

Comment: Panda may have been hanging the installer msiexec.exe processes.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this answer because it was what actually worked for me.

- Go into task manager, kill all MSIEXEC.exe processes. Repeat as necessary.
- Go to Windows update website instead of relying on automatic updates.
- At some point Windows update will do some kind of hack to prevent the mis-application of not-applicable service packs.